Bacnet Bac0 issue while reading device from outside network
I am using library ( and bacnet ) first time, so maybe I am doing it totally wrong but I have situation that in some local network under IP: 192.168.1.215 there is some Eclypse ECY-Tu203-96B019, and I have access to router under address 10.x.y.z, I have setup port forwarding there to be able to access 192.168.1.215.
I was told that via this Eclypse I am able to read from many devices in this network ( its some kind IP Driver at least what I heard )
. While using nmap I see:
sudo nmap --script bacnet-info --script-args full=yes -sU -n -sV -p 47808 10.x.y.z
Starting Nmap 7.95 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2024-08-09 09:34 CEST
Nmap scan report for 10.x.y.z
Host is up (0.25s latency).

PORT      STATE SERVICE VERSION
47808/udp open  bacnet
| bacnet-info: 
|   Vendor ID: Distech Controls Inc. (364)
|   Vendor Name: Distech Controls, Inc.
|   Object-identifier: 1215
|   Firmware: 1.14.17191.1
|   Application Software: 1.13.19189.607
|   Object Name: ECY-TU203-96B019
|   Model Name: ECY-TU203 Rev 1.0A
|   Description: 
|_  Location: 


so according to that I can assume that router with port forwarding is fine as Object name is fine ( I have a photo from bacnet config of this device ).
So I try with this script:
import BAC0

print(BAC0.version)

bbmdIP = '10.x.y.z:47808'
bbmdTTL = 900
bacnet = BAC0.lite(bbmdAddress=bbmdIP, bbmdTTL=bbmdTTL) #Connect

print(bacnet.vendorName.strValue)
print(bacnet.modelName.strValue)

whois_results = bacnet.whois()
print("WhoIs results:", whois_results)

print(bacnet.devices)

bacnet.discover(networks='known')

but I get a response:
23.07.03
2024-08-09 10:36:14,549 - INFO    | Starting BAC0 version 23.07.03 (Lite)
2024-08-09 10:36:14,549 - INFO    | Use BAC0.log_level to adjust verbosity of the app.
2024-08-09 10:36:14,549 - INFO    | Ex. BAC0.log_level('silence') or BAC0.log_level('error')
2024-08-09 10:36:14,549 - INFO    | Starting TaskManager
2024-08-09 10:36:14,551 - INFO    | Using ip : 192.168.1.33 on port 47808 | broadcast : 192.168.1.255
2024-08-09 10:36:14,560 - INFO    | Starting app...
2024-08-09 10:36:14,561 - INFO    | BAC0 started
2024-08-09 10:36:14,561 - INFO    | Registered as Foreign Device
2024-08-09 10:36:14,561 - INFO    | Device instance (id) : 3056745
2024-08-09 10:36:14,562 - INFO    | Update Local COV Task started (required to support COV)
b'SERVISYS inc.'
b'BAC0 Scripting Tool'
WhoIs results: []
[]
2024-08-09 10:36:18,670 - INFO    | Found those networks : set()
2024-08-09 10:36:18,670 - INFO    | No BACnet network found, attempting a simple whois using provided device instances limits (0 - 4194303)

192.168.1.33 is my local machine IP.
Whgat am i doing it wrong ? thanks!

So, it seems that the bbmd registration is successful, great. But the Distech device also needs to be able to send messages to your local device, as BACnetIP is connection less. Did you setup port forwarding on your network aswell? Also register with your routers IP of course. Not sure if you did that.

hmm what do you mean by port forwarding on my network ? I should forward connections to my localhost  from 47808 to 10.x.y.z ?
" Using ip : 192.168.1.33" its my localhost ip not router hmm so you say I should change it also ?

Yes. you need port forwarding on both networks to be able to send and recieve BACnet IP messages across the NAT of the routers. And additionally, you need to do the foreign device registration with the IP of your local router.

I don't know about 'BAC0', but it might be the case that your question needs more clarity; can your network access the other network - without port-forwarding (& without a BBMD)?  Are you referring to a regular IP router or a BACnet router?  Have you tried with a tool such as YABE/Wireshark/VTS for contrast (/info)?

@DennisVM-D2i well I had some issues with VPN , finally it works, and yesh wireshark is showing UDP packets coming back :) I had other issue , get NAK but its some device setting ( someone else has access to this device so I need to wait )

@FrancMo With VPNs, I'd question the 'allow' rules for both ICMP(v4) 'Echo Requests'/pings and UDP/IP (aka BACnet/IP), attempt to test with ping - in case it is enabled upon/allowed by the device, and then move on to testing with BACnet/IP.  Some devices don't fully (/properly) the BACnet Standard, or at least their implementation of it can exhibit a bug or two.  You might want to specify what kind/type of NAK (?).

thanks, yeah I saw in wireshark some ICMP failing :)
